# Python Increasing Resolution of Converting from Numpy Array to Image using Matplotlib and PIL

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm currently using Python 3.7.3 on Linux CentOS 7. I am conducting research related to NASA's THEMIS All-Sky-Imager (ASI) database, where I attempt to extract auroral images (keograms) from the .cdf files (which describe visual information for each auroral epoch in the form of a NumPy array). I convert the NumPy array to 'approximately' its corresponding image using Matplotlib and PIL (Python Imaging Library) in the following code:

*I would like to note that I'm using the Python3 console within the Linux terminal. Also, I am using the SpacePy Library to read the .cdf file using the pycdf.CDF(...) function.*

```
# Define .cdf file object as downloaded from NASA THEMIS ASI Database
>>> cdf = pycdf.CDF('/projectnb/burbsp/big/SATELLITE/themis/data/thg/l1/asi/gill/2008/01/thg_l1_asf_gill_2008011403_v01.cdf')
# Display .cdf file objects; 'thg_asf_gill' defines the set of arrays which contains the visual information stored for each image; i.e. cdf['thg_asf_gill'][0,:,:] would define the first epoch array up to cdf['thg_asf_gill'][1197,:,:] which is the last epoch array (a total 1198 epoch arrays).
>>> print(cdf)
range_epoch: CDF_EPOCH [2]
thg_asf_gill: CDF_UINT2 [1198, 256, 256]
thg_asf_gill_column: CDF_UINT2 [256] NRV
thg_asf_gill_epoch: CDF_EPOCH [1198]
thg_asf_gill_epoch0: CDF_EPOCH [] NRV
thg_asf_gill_row: CDF_UINT2 [256] NRV
thg_asf_gill_tend: CDF_REAL8 [1198]
thg_asf_gill_time: CDF_REAL8 [1198]
```

Then, I use what I've seen suggested on stack overflow to convert the NumPy array (take the last epoch array as an example) into an image plot.

```
>>> pyplot.imshow(cdf['thg_asf_gill'][1197,:,:])
>>> pyplot.show()
```

The resulting image (Image Plot of Aurora) can be found below:

[image: Image Plot of Aurora]

As you can see there are some features that aren't shown because they are a bit too dim, so I tried to play around with the color scaling using the following:

```
pyplot.clim(vmin,vmax)
```

Where vmin and vmax are some values; in particular I use vmin = 5000 and vmax = 10000 (I also played around with other values), the resulting image (Altered Image Plot of Aurora) is:

[image: Altered Image Plot of Aurora]

The image becomes too distorted (resolution-wise).

The NASA THEMIS ASI image is found below:

[image: NASA THEMIS ASI Image]

As you can see, the image yielded from PIL and Matplotlib is somewhat of a transormation/rotation of the actual NASA image. Also, the dim-ish features are lost. So, what's a way to increase the resolution of the resultant image such that the the bright features don't become too bright/distorted (as seen from the altered image) and the dim features are enhanced?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html

Comment: Do you think logarithmic scaling would suit my purposes? Or which type would help achieve the desired outcome I've outlined in the question?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Because I don't know how the photograph you show has been created from the data. So you need to experiment with different normalizations.

Comment: You could try *"histogram equalisation"* to try and make all areas intelligible...